# How to remove space if is after a slash in php

Tags: php, file, storage, media, disk

Example:

```
/var/www/media/ Book 1 Chapter 1 - Video 1 Part 1
```

to become

```
/var/www/media/Book 1 Chapter 1 - Video 1 Part 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So assuming that this spacing is a result of this concatenation:

`"/var/www/media/" . $filepath`

Then the issue is with the `$filepath` variable. You can fix it by simply using the PHP `trim()` function to remove whitespace before and after the string.

Before:
"    This is my string.     "

After:
"This is my string."